# Sequences approximating sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is known that convergent sequences approximate certain numbers. For example, the sequence $\dfrac12,\dfrac12+\dfrac14, \dfrac12+\dfrac14+\dfrac18,\cdots$ etc approximates the number $1$. Are there sequences that approximate sequences? In other words, some global operation would be applied to the sequence as a whole at each stage, thereby taking it closer and closer to the final sequence. Each term would therefore be a sequence rather than just a number as in the above example.

Comment: You should define a norm over the sequence differences, the most obvious is $||s_1 - s_2|| = ||s_1|| - ||s_2||$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That's part of the field of Functional Analysis. Within this field of Mathematics, the [sequence spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) are studied.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Accepted (in 11 minutes).

Comment: field of Mathematica?

Comment: @user160738 I can't believe I did this. :-(

Comment: @Raghib I'm glad I could help.